# Dynamo UpdateItem AccessDeniedException with default LambdaRole

Tags: go, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, aws-sdk-go

I'm having difficulties getting the right role to execute a Dynamo UpdateItem in my golang lambda handler.

I've deployed the function using the serverless framework with the following config:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  environment: ${file(./env/config.${self:provider.stage}.yml)}
  iamRoleStatements: # TODO: create special roles and restrict access per lambda
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource:
        - "Fn::GetAtt": [ myTable, Arn ]

resources:
  Resources:
    myTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      Properties:
        TableName: myTable-${opt:stage, 'dev'}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: UserID
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: UserID
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1

functions:
  myFunc:
    handler: bin/myFunc
    events:
      - http:
          path: myFunc
          method: post
          authorizer: app-auth
          cors: true
```

The handler uses the golang aws-sdk to create a session and call UpdateItem on the table:

```
    sess, err := session.NewSession()
    svc := dynamodb.New(sess)
    input := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
        ...
    }
    _, err = svc.UpdateItem(input)
```

This throws the exception:

`AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::{acct}:assumed-role/myservice-stage-us-east-1-lambdaRole/myservice-stage-myfunc`

The `User: arn:aws:sts::{acct}:assumed-role/myservice-stage-us-east-1-lambdaRole` is a role that has the correct permissions:

[image]

I'm not sure what the `/myservice-stage-myfunc` part of the User is in the exception as nothing of the sort exists in the IAM console.

Is there some kind of config step I'm missing. To my knowledge, the IAM permissions setup in the serverless.yaml should apply to all functions. However, the assumed role for when working with the go-aws-sdk seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB has sub resources that often need access. To ensure that you are also addressing those sub items I would recommend adding a wildcard `*` onto the end of the resource. To do this I prefer to use the `serverless-pseudo-parameters` plugin (you can install it quickly with `serverless plugin install --name serverless-pseudo-parameters`) and then use it to more cleanly describe the resource like:

```
      Resource:
        - arn:aws:dynamodb:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:table/myTable-${opt:stage, 'dev'}*
```

Comment: I ended up using * for now.